# F# Select from SQL Server table synonym

Tags: sql, f#, synonym, type-providers

I have a synonym for a table in my SQL Server database.

I want to select rows from the table but when I create data context with a type provider I don't see the synonym in the created data context.

Synonym is created like this:

```sql
CREATE SYNONYM [AnotherDatabase_dbo].[MyTable] FOR [AnotherDatabase].[dbo].[MyTable]
```

I create data context like this:

```ml
type dbSchema = SqlDataConnection<"Data Source=MyServer\MyInstance;Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;Integrated Security=SSPI;">
let db = dbSchema.GetDataContext ()
```

How can I access the synonym from F#?

Comment: +1 for introducing me to SYNONYM ... never ran into this and I thought I've been around SQL Server a bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More of a workaround than a solution, but the code below allows you to access a synonym through F#.
This uses the `FSharp.Data` library, available through NuGet or here: http://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/.
NB: Requires SQL 2012 or above.

```
open FSharp.Data

[<Literal>]
let connectionString = @"Data Source=MyServer\MyInstance;Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;Integrated Security=SSPI;"

[<Literal>]
let query = "select Id, Name from MyTable" 

type OptionQuery = SqlCommandProvider<query, connectionString>
let cmd = new OptionQuery()

cmd.AsyncExecute() 
|> Async.RunSynchronously
|> Seq.iter (fun row -> printfn "Found row: %d %s" row.Id row.Name)

System.Console.Write("Done")
System.Console.ReadKey()
```